# strings appear as weird symbols

Tags: c, string, random, character, extract

I have been having trouble with this with another assignment where my strings would printf as nonsensical symbols, like a question mark in a diamond or random characters.

This time I am trying to do

```
char *word = "blah";
printf("word: %s", word);
```

This gives me gibberish that isn't even the same length as the word.  I have included string.h.

What I am trying to do is take a string, append two letters one at a time to either the front or back of the string, and then extract the characters from the back half of the string.  Using the following method to append:

```
int len = strlen(word);
word[len] = 'd';
```

Also, how do I extract say the last two characters?  I'm assuming I'd extract it by getting the strlen of word and turning it into a character array and copying from indice to indice. Is there a better way? Also, random question:  when do I use '\0'?  Is it needed in this case?

Much thanks to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Please post the code that prints out gibberish. With regards to appending, you can't say word[len] unless the char array you're using has enough space allocated. if you say char *word = "hello"; and try to append a letter... it's a bad idea!

Comment: FYI, string literal `blah` pointed by `word` resides in read only location and is not modifiable. Infact it is - `const char* word = "blah";`

Answer (score 3):

Your code finds the length of `word`, a number which *does not* include the null terminator at the end.  You then proceed to overwrite the terminator with the following line:

```
word[len] = 'd';
```

So now you have a string which does not terminate properly and won't play nicely with I/O functions.  Remember; indeces start at zero.  A string of length `x` has accessible characters in the range of `0` through `x-1`.

Aside from that, you don't show us how you created `word` in the first place, so there may be a problem there as well.  If you didn't initialize it properly to begin with you're probably just stomping all over memory that you shouldn't be modifying.

EDIT: Ok, so you have posted the code where you create the string, and here is another problem:

```
char *word = "blah";
```

That should really be

```
const char *word = "blah";
```

because `word` points to read only memory.  You are not allowed to modify what `word` points to.  Instead, create an array if you need to modify the string later on:

```
char word[] = "blah";
```

Comment: Even if I just create the string and printf it as shown and don't alter it in any other way, I still get gibberish.  Help???

Comment: @user963070: Yeah, there is something else going on that you haven't shown us if that's the case.

Comment: I don't know what to say.  I restarted Ubuntu and now it's gone.  I have had problems this in the past, though, where I get the desired string plus weird symbols after it, and restarting did not help.  They were completely random characters.  I don't know what to show that would help.

Comment: @user963070: "Weird symbols" is a tell tale sign that your string is not properly terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Here word is a pointer to character so its malloc is fix at a time. so you want to any change in this string you have to use `memcpy` functions or `strcpy,strcat` functions.

Using these functions you can append any number of characters before or after the string